# Oracle Database 19c - Find the non-default location of PFile

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have an **Oracle Database 19**C running in a docker container. I cannot find the *Pfile/SPFile* in the default location of *$ORACLE_HOME/dbs*. But the database is up and running.
It could have been started with a non-default location of Pfile. The output of parameter *SPFILE* is blank too. How can I find the location of non-default Pfile? Any ideas?

Thanks,
Madhuri

Answer (score 0):

I found the location of PFile in Alert Log.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).